# How to transfer data from a variable nodejs server to PHP?

Tags: php, node.js

In my nodejs, I use sockets which output data to the user:

```
io.emit ('notify', {
msg_link: `/Notify_link`,
msg_dep: `${me.personaName} ${data.code}`,
status: 'success'
});
```

All work good. At javascript i process the data:

```
socket.on('notify', (data) => {
    if (data.id === USER_ID) {
        const link = data.msg_link;
        const message = data.msg_dep;
        updateNotify_info(message, link);
        Inv.update();
    }
});
```

And `const link` make `POST` to my laravel application and there I already enter data into the database:

```
public function getNotify_link() {
    Notify::create(
        [
        'user_id' => $this->user->id,
        'title' => 'Success',
        'message' => 'Name: {name} Code: {code}',
        'status' => '1',
        ]);
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'status' => 'success']);
}
```

The question is, how do I pass the variables that I get in nodejs: `${me.personaName}` and `${data.code}` to the site’s `getNotify_link()` function to add this data to the database?

**EDIT:** `updateNotify_info()` function at JS:

```
function updateNotify_info(message, svg, link) {
    $.post(`${link}`, function (data) {
        var notification = $('<div>', {"class": "notification"});
        var block = $('<div>', {"class": "notification__content"});

        block.append($('<div>', {"text": 'Title', "class": "notification__title"}));
        block.append($('<div>', {"text": `${message}`, "class": "notification__text"}));

        block.append($('<div>', {"text": new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10), "class": "notification__date"}));

        notification.append(`${svg}`);           
        notification.append(block);

        notification.prependTo("#notifications .scroll");


        $('.sidebar-nav__item_notify').addClass(' sidebar-nav__notifications sidebar-nav__notifications_unread sidebar-nav__notifications_animated')
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.sidebar-nav__item_notify').removeClass(' sidebar-nav__notifications sidebar-nav__notifications_animated')
        },2000);
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're making a HTTP POST request from the NodeJS code to the PHP server. Therefore you can include the necessary data in the body of the request (just like the browser would if you'd submitted that data via a HTML form).

Comment: But could I ask why you have separate NodeJS and PHP to begin with? If the NodeJS is just to handle the sockets, then why not write that functionality in PHP? PHP can also provide websocket functionality. Then it would be easier to share the data, state information etc, and you wouldn't need to maintain two separate codebases in different languages, different deployed environments and so on. Of course there may be more to it than that, but on the face of it, using NodeJS just to provide websockets when the rest of your app is written in PHP doesn't seem very worthwhile.

Comment: I agree with you that this can be done more conveniently, but while the site is in development, I check all the features and only then I will determine which is better :)

And about the question, can you tell me how can I pass these variables from nodejs to PHP?

Comment: Well like I said you have to put them in the body of your request. But I can't see precisely how you're sending your request now - for that we would need to see the code of the `updateNotify_info` function. BTW It looks like from the socket you are sending the name and code inside a single string, but this is unstructured. it might be better to transmit that in JSON format to begin with so the Javascript code which receives it can split it easily into two different values, in order to send to Laravel.

Comment: Or...is there any reason why the NodeJS server cannot send the message direct to Laravel. Does it need to be sent from the user's browser, for any specific reason? Or it that just how you've designed it right now?

Comment: i update my question and include `updateNotify_info()` func

Comment: ok so first you have to split `message` into two, to get the two different properties from it (like I said above, this would be simpler if your socket server had returned it in a machine-readable format originally). Then you have to send it in the $.post request. As per https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/, you can supply data as the second argument to the $.post function and it will be sent to the server.

Comment: Dealing with the data we've got now (without making the suggested change to JSON format),  then assuming we can reliably split `message` using the space in the middle (i.e. assuming those values will never have any spaces within them), then `var data = message.split(' '); $.post(\`${link}\`, { name: data[0], code: data[1] }, function (data) {`....might work.

Comment: okay, i will try it, thank you for reply